# Firebase fetching the desired data

Tags: database, firebase

I want to retrieve the email addresses of all the child nodes, but when I execute the following command, it only shows the last child's email address.
Here is the data from Firebase:

[image: data]

and here is the code I used to retrieve the data:

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("user")
    .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            //user userr = snapshot.getValue(user.class);
            //System.out.println(userr.email);
            String c=snapshot.child("email").getValue().toString();
            String longi=snapshot.child("longitude").getValue().toString();
            String latt=snapshot.child("email").getValue().toString();

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),c+" "+longi+" "+latt,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            //  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"sadjsakdn",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            //        User user = snapshot.getValue(User.class);
            //System.out.println(user.email);
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"errorrrr",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("user").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            Iterable<DataSnapshot> children = dataSnapshot.getChildren();

            for (DataSnapshot child : children) {
                User value = child.getValue(User.class);

                if (value != null) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "List of emails: " + value.getEmail(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

And the User class is a basic POJO class:

```
public class User {
public String name,email,password,userType;
public int lattitude,longitude;

public String getEmail() {
    return name;
}

public void setEmail(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
```